# Why does Openlayers plugin crash QGIS 1.7.4?

Tags: openlayers-2

When I open the openlayers plugin my qgis 1.7.4 crashes.

I use Win7.

I'm using the CRS Google Mercator and QGIS crashes.

However, I've install the QGIS 1.9.90 and the plugin works in this version... but... There are always a but... the Google Satellite images don't adjust with my shapefiles. It's a strange behaviour...

Any suggestion to solve this?

Comment: What CRS is your project set to? Do you have any custom settings on the CRS?  You need to let it use the Google projection.

Comment: Do you have the latest version of OpenLayers plugin? Check for updates in plugin installer.

Comment: Also, try asking on the qgis mailing lists. I think you would get a more direct response there. The plugin dev may even be watching. http://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/qgis-user http://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/qgis-developer